# VBA Looping Iteration

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

I need help with this code I have. It works, but I want to make it into a loop instead of manually entering another line of code. So basically instead of having 3 blocks of code, I want to it be a single block.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:D1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveCell.Offset(2, -4).Range("A1:D1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 8).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveCell.Offset(3, -8).Range("A1:D1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 16).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Should be like this:

```
Loop 3{
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:D1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
}
```

I'm not sure how I can iterate through cells in VBA. Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is what i am trying to do. Thanks

```
1   2   3   4                   
5   6   7   8          -->       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
9   10  11  12
```

Comment: What exactly should `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1")` point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without selecting each time, try this:

```
For i = 1 To 3

    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Range("A1:D1").Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, i * 4)

Next i
```

Comment: the math on your offsets doesn't quite match up to the question

Comment: I think the offsets in the original question have a typo (specifically the offset in the third iteration), my solution produces the correct result based on the OP's edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty much the same as @Valon's, but I didn't want to continue to use the `Range("A1:D1")` specification because it's rather unusual. Instead, I'm using `.Resize()` to get the cells adjacent to the `ActiveCell`.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 2
    ActiveCell.Resize(, 4).offset(i, 0).Cut ActiveCell.offset(0, i * 4)
Next i
```